# Node.js / Awssum for S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

Hi there: I'm wondering if anyone knows a method for listing all files inside of an S3 bucket with node.js and Awssum, starting with the *most recent* file first.

By default, my code takes the first created file.

```
function getFileList(callback){
s3.ListObjects(coldBucket, function(err, data) {
    var fileList = getFilenames(data, coldBucketPath);
    callback(fileList);
});
};
```

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What does `getFilenames()` return?

Comment: It returns an array of file names with the amazon image path

Comment: Could it be that you simply want `callback(fileList.reverse());`?

Comment: Tried that, it can't work because there is tens of thousands of images in the bucket, and you need to set a number of Max Keys...

Comment: The [S3 docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html) say that you can use a `marker` parameter to set the starting point for getting items from a bucket. I can't find the JS library you are using so I can't look at the code to say how to do it.

Comment: @Tomalak this is the library he's using https://github.com/appsattic/node-awssum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is Andy, creator of AwsSum.

That's correct, there is no way of asking S3 for the filenames in order of inserted time. However, you can get it using the LastModified.

If you'd like to see an example to get all the keys, see this example here:

- https://github.com/appsattic/node-awssum-scripts/blob/master/bin/amazon-s3-list.js

You could then store each item in an array, then sort it using LastModified. The underscore library contains a function that would be useful for this:

- http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#sortBy

Answer (score 0):

I looking at http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html, I don't believe s3 allows you to specify the sort order of the response.

However, you may be able to work around that by changing your file structure to include folders named after the date they were created, then you could do a couple of `ListObjects` requests with prefixes for recent days/months/etc.

For example, you could have `year-month` folder names so your file structure looks like this:

```
bucket_name/
    - 2012-3/
        - file2.jpg
        - file3.jpg
    - 2012-2/
        - file1.jpg
```

and then before you make your request, do this

```
var now = new Date();
coldBucket.Prefix = now.getFullYear() + "-" + now.getMonth();
```

And then if you wanted older stuff you'd have to do a followup request for previous months.

(If you have too many files even for that, you could try `year-month-day`)